# parsing a list of strings based on values in the string

Tags: python, arrays, string

I scraped data from a website and output the results in a list using the following code to get the following output using beautifulsoup and requests:

```
['1\n',
 ' Saul Alvarez*',
 '1545\n',
 '\n\n',
 '  middle\n',
 '  30\n',
 ' 53\xa01\xa02\n',
 ' \n',
 'orthodox\n',
 'Guadalajara, Mexico',
 '2\n',
 ' Tyson Fury',
 '1030\n',
 '\n\n',
 '  heavy\n',
 '  32\n',
 ' 30\xa00\xa01\n',
 ' \n',
 'orthodox\n',
 'Wilmslow, United Kingdom',
 '3\n',
 ' Errol Spence Jr',
 '697.2\n',
 '\n\n',
 '  welter\n',
 '  30\n',
 ' 27\xa00\xa00\n',
 ' \n',
 'southpaw\n',
 'Desoto, USA',
 '4\n',
 ' Terence Crawford',
 '658.9\n',
 '\n\n',
 '  welter\n',
...
```

I'm having difficulty parsing this list wherever there is an integer + '\n'.
So ideally I would like the output to be a list of lists :

```
[[
'1\n',
 ' Saul Alvarez*',
 '1545\n',
 '\n\n',
 '  middle\n',
 '  30\n',
 ' 53\xa01\xa02\n',
 ' \n',
 'orthodox\n',
 'Guadalajara, Mexico'
],
['2\n',
 ' Tyson Fury',
 '1030\n',
 '\n\n',
 '  heavy\n',
 '  32\n',
 ' 30\xa00\xa01\n',
 ' \n',
 'orthodox\n',
 'Wilmslow, United Kingdom']
['3\n',
 ' Errol Spence Jr',
 '697.2\n',
 '\n\n',
 '  welter\n',
 '  30\n',
 ' 27\xa00\xa00\n',
 ' \n',
 'southpaw\n',
 'Desoto, USA'],
...]
```

Comment: so you meant, you want your ist list to be transformed to second  list? or please clarify
or are you sure every sublist will have the same length that is 9?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are 2 things going on, and I'll address only the first.

You can drop blanks and `'\n'` because those are newline characters, i.e. linefeeds.

```
li = ['1\n',
 ' Saul Alvarez*',
 '1545\n',
 '\n\n',
 '  middle\n',
 '  30\n',
 ' 53\xa01\xa02\n',
 ' \n',
 
]

li = [val.replace(r"\n","") for val in li]
li = [val.strip() for val in li if val.strip()]

print(li)
```

That outputs:

```
['1', 'Saul Alvarez*', '1545', 'middle', '30', '53\xa01\xa02']
```

Second issue, which I won't address here as we don't know the html format which you haven't given, is that you are grabbing all the element values (the text in each tag) without looking at the HTML markup's structure.  That's the wrong approach to take.

I assume that if you look at the page's source you might find something like `<div class="name">Saul Alvarez</div><div class="weightclass">middle</div>`.  Using the markup's annotation and semantic context is more productive than trying to guess at the structure from the above list with 6 elements.  BeautifulSoup can do it, trying using `soup.select("div.name")` for example.

The nice thing with `soup.select` which uses CSS selectors is that you can pre-test your query in your browser's dev tools.

Just remember, `soup.select` will return a list of html elements, from which you'll want to look at the `value`.